# Validation message don´t receive the error from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the error passing throw the API to the Controller and after i show on view, but i just can show on `ValidationSummary`. How i show to the `ValidationMessageFor` ?

I have this in my Model:

```
public class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be less than 10")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be higher than 20")]
    public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

And this in my MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> create(User user)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/api/users/");

            //HTTP POST
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<User>("create",user);

            var response_api = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, response_api.ToString());
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Where i'm returning the response from api in `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, response_api.ToString());`

but the response just has sent to the  `@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` and not for the correspondent `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`, why? what i can do to this work? and one more question, is normal the response from `DataAnnotations` return me this error:

> {"type":"https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|fdb6e77c-4d37747fda3a69c9.1.6cd6fd5a_","errors":{"Name":["Username is Required"]}}

and not just the `Username is Required`.

Comment: You need to do `ModelState.AddModelError("Name", response_api.ToString());` to associate it with that field.

Comment: worked, but now i have other question, how i use that `ModelState.AddModelError("Name", response_api.ToString());` to multiple data imagine Name,Password and email?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in ModelState.AddModelError identifies the Property name in the Model on which bind the error to.

While it is possibile for you to parse PostAsJsonAsync response and bind each error to the correct property, calling your underlying API without validating input model first is not a best practice, though.

I suggest you change your code into something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> create(User user)
    {
        If(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           using (var client = new HttpClient())
           {
              client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/api/users/");

              //HTTP POST
              var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<User>("create",user);

              var response_api = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

              if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
              {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
              }
              else
              {
                 ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, response_api.ToString());
              }
           }
       }
       return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: "parse PostAsJsonAsync response and bind each error to the correct property", like depend of response from api create one specific ModelState?

Comment: Yes, but my point is you don't need to call the API at all for validating the User model in input, since you have validation rules on class, ModelState will validate it for you, and add each property error accordingly. If the model passes the validation, then you'll call the API, that won't return other validation errors (provided you share model validation rules with the API, of course).

Comment: Also, API call can return other kind of errors (for instance authentication errors, internal faults, ...) that do not depend strictly on the data you are posting. Your client code should log details on the error occurred and return some generic but self explaining error message in ValidationSummary. Page users aren't interested in json strings or intrigued errors code, they just need to be instructed if the error depends on something they wrote or not.